# Error while deploying Google Cloud Task Client

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-tasks-api

I am trying to create a task using Google Cloud Tasks but i'm encountering an error.

My code compiles perfectly but when it reaches the Cloud Tasks initialization line:

```
const data = snap.data();

let expirationInSeconds
if(data.booking_date_ts - Date.now() > 172800000){
    expirationInSeconds = (Date.now() + 172800000) / 1000
}else{
    expirationInSeconds = (Date.now() + 180000) / 1000
}

const project = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId
const location = 'us-central1'
const queue = 'reminders'

const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient() // This is the error line
const queuePath = tasksClient.queuePath(project, location, queue)

const url = `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/bookingExpirationCallback`
const docPath = snap.ref.path
const payload = { docPath }

const task = {
    httpRequest: {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        url,
        body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64'),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    },
    scheduleTime: {
        seconds: expirationInSeconds
    }
}

return await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task });
```

i am getting the following error:

> Error: Node.js v10.0.0 is a minimum requirement

which is weird because their documentation says:

> Our client libraries follow the Node.js release schedule. Libraries are compatible with all current active and maintenance versions of Node.js.

and my current Node.js version is: **v12.16.3**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my Node.js version was set to 12.16.3 but the process.version was 8.3.2.

**How to fix it?**

Modify package.json engine from:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
```

to

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
```

Comment: Bro i have the same issue, how to solve this, i did as you told like   "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.3"
  }, still same error

Comment: @PranR.V you have to set it to "10", not to 12.16.3. Let me know if it worked

Comment: It didnt, i am using serverless framework so in serverless.yml there is a field called runtime which when set to node10 it worked